# Coldfusion Query broken column structure

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery

A coldfusion query's column can be referenced like a 2D array from what I know of my past experience. Sometimes though I get this issue.

1. create query from spreadsheet
2. put column names into an array
3. only get first element when trying to access the row
4. have to use a workaround

```
//imports is a query object after this function
var imports = convertSpreadsheetWOHeaders(spreadsheet, 1);
//this is used to give name values in the json struct, not to access the query columns
var jsonHeaders = ListToArray("number,constructiontype,description,site_address,parcel,permit_date,note_Applicant,note_Contractor,valuation,note_Bld_Fees,note_Other_Fees");
//this gives me ["col_1","col_2","col_3",,,etc]. used to access query columns
var columnHeaders = imports.getColumnNames();
writeDump(imports[columnHeaders[1]]);
writeDump(imports);
```

[image: output of the writeDump]

I am left with just the first element in column one. And I get of course:

```
Message: You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.
```

When trying to do this:

```
structInsert(jsonStruct,jsonHeaders[j],imports[columnHeaders[j]][i]);
```

However, this works:

```
 writeDump(ListToArray(ArrayToList(imports[columnHeaders[1]],'|'),'|',true));
```

[image: converted to list then array]

I first do a dump of **imports["col_1"]** and i get only the **first element**.
Then I do a dump of **ListToArray(ArrayToList(imports["col_1"]))** like you see in the above image and it gives me the **whole column.**

Why can I not access the column correctly in the first place?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what your question is.

Comment: Sorry, all. Just added the question. Why does it work after the conversions?

Comment: The last screen shot is a dump of what object: columnHeaders, imports, ...?

Comment: @Leigh dump of first column in imports 
`writeDump(ListToArray(ArrayToList(imports[columnHeaders[i]],'|'),'|',true));`

Comment: Ohh wait... if `imports` is a *query* object that would explain why `imports["col_1"]` does not work. Traditionally in CF, `#queryName.columnName#` or `queryName["columnName"]` are treated as a shortcut for `#queryName.columnName[1]#` ie Value in the first row of the query, which is obviously a simple value.  `ArrayToList` is an exception to this convention. I imagine it behaves differently because that function *requires* an array, not a simple value.

Comment: @Leigh. Yes I made a comment above imports variable to clarify that. That makes sense. I guess it's normally most convenient to have this shortcut format?? ArrayToList must _force_ it to return the array format. Could you post this as an answer please.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, because there is no way the function could work if passed in a simple string. So it always uses the query column array. Which version are you using? Unless I am missing something, the code seemed to work fine : http://trycf.com/gist/3651354432ba716e4f726147fb9af81c/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115336/discussion-between-matt-wilde-and-leigh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Real Problem:

**I was originally trying to access the jsonHeaders list as an array without doing `ListToArray()` on it. After that my function worked.**

***BUT. This next part is helpful.***

When attempting to access a query object, doing `queryObject["columnName"]` is considered a shortcut of `queryObject["columnName"][1]` so coldfusion will just give you the first element.

But when I said `ListToArray(ArrayToList())` coldfusion sees that `ArrayToList` MUST take in an array so an exception is made and the column is returned as an array.

To get a column back as an array to work with you can do a couple things

```
ListToArray(ArrayToList(query["column"]));
ListToArray(valueList(query.column));
valueArray(query, "column");
```